# TS2774: This condition will always return true since this function is always defined. Did you mean to call it instead

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
interface A {
        a: () => boolean;
    }

    class AImpl implements A {
        public a(): boolean {
            return true;
        }
    }

    it('should fail', function () {
        const aImpl = new AImpl();
        if (aImpl.a) { // TS2774: This condition will always return true since this function is always defined. Did you mean to call it instead?
            console.log("always true");
        }
    });

    it('why success', function () {
        const aImpl = new AImpl();
        if (!aImpl.a) { // nothing happens here
            console.log('always false');
        }
    });
```

why `aImp.a` reports TS2774, but `!aImpl.a` works well?

And is there any way to find the property-dereference on a method declaration?

Comment: the condition should be `aImpl.a()`, you're not calling the function

Comment: I'm not familiar with TypeScript, but if the language does this kind of checking for you, maybe the test is unnecessary.

Comment: yeah, I know now. Mistake has been made.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Ramesh Reddy in the comments, if you call `if(aImpl.a)`, it will always return `true` because you defined the property `aImpl.a`.
You essentially convert the reference of the property to boolean, and that will always be true because this property is defined.

What you likely wanted to do is to call the function that you implemented.
In other words, `if (aImpl.a())`.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug I wrote. What I want to know is why the second way never report anything. If I wrote like the first way, I'll notice that I was wrong.

Comment: ps. IDE's auto-completion always completes as property dereference if I define the method like I quoted

Comment: You're checking if the function exists in the first one, and Typescript knows based on your interface that the function does exists. So that check is useless. But there might be a situation where the function might not exists in the second one and Typescript doesn't know that, so it can show you any error.

Comment: @user17437960 according to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html it seems like it only checks for `if(true)`. I refer to the "we forgot to call isAdministrator" part of the page.

Comment: @user17437960 did it answer your question?

Comment: still can't catch the point. So the conclusion we lead to is unit test?

Comment: Is it about "property-dereference" that you mentioned in your question?